Change a one to many association to an one to one
I use spring boot 3.3.2
I have an entity with a one to many . I  need to switch it to a one to one association (unidirectional or not). I search to not change schema of the db
@Entity
public class Deposit{

    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "deposit", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Claim> claims = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Claim{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_deposit", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Deposit deposit;

}

Does this make sense
@Entity
public class Deposit{
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "depot")
    private Claim claims;
}

@Entity
public class Claim{
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_deposit")
    @NotNullll
    private Deposit deposit;
}

